# What does the c underscore expression `c_` do exactly?

Tags: python, numpy

It seems to be some kind of horizontal concatenation, but I could not find any documentation online. Here a minimal working example:

```
In [1]: from numpy import c_
In [2]: a = ones(4)
In [3]: b = zeros((4,10))    
In [4]: c_[a,b]
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Top tip: In IPython, you can use `?` to get more info on any object. Try running `c_?`.

Comment: @ThomasK, thanks, that was what I needed. c_? provided me with all the info. Can you post an answer so I can select it?

Comment: The simplest reference is the numpy manual: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html (for everyone who works without IPython).

Comment: Or call `help(c_)` in other interpreter

Comment: It would be good to explain the difference between [np.c_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) and [np.c](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) if there is one. Both say: "*This is short-hand for `np.r_['-1,2,0', index expression]`*" referring to [np.r_](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy.r_)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use IPython's `?` syntax to get more information:

```
In [2]: c_?
Type:       CClass
Base Class: <class 'numpy.lib.index_tricks.CClass'>
String Form:<numpy.lib.index_tricks.CClass object at 0x9a848cc>
Namespace:  Interactive
Length:     0
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py
Docstring:
Translates slice objects to concatenation along the second axis.

This is short-hand for ``np.r_['-1,2,0', index expression]``, which is
useful because of its common occurrence. In particular, arrays will be
stacked along their last axis after being upgraded to at least 2-D with
1's post-pended to the shape (column vectors made out of 1-D arrays).

For detailed documentation, see `r_`.

Examples
--------
>>> np.c_[np.array([[1,2,3]]), 0, 0, np.array([[4,5,6]])]
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: man I can not even guess how many times having made the acquaintance of this simple `?` earlier would have saved time.

Comment: -1 because the doc needs further elaboration. "Translates slice objects to concatenation" => the examples given use no slice objects at all. How can we understand this?

Comment: I agree with @creanion - Numpy usually has a very nice documentation, but this specific one is kind of awkward. It is pretty much "read the docs for `r_`" and unfollowable on it's own. (Though I generally dislike the underscore functions of Numpy as is, they are very un-Pythonic and usually produce hard-to-read code.)

Answer (score 78):

It took me a lot of time to understand but it seems I finally got it.

All you have to do is **add along second axis.**

let's take :

```
np.c_[np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]
```

But there isn't second axis. So we mentally add one.

so shape of both array  becomes `(3,1)`.

So resultant shape would be (3,1+1) which is (3,2).
which is the shape of result -

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Another ex.:

```
np.c_[np.array([[1,2,3]]), 0, 0, np.array([[4,5,6]])]
```

shapes:

`np.array([[1,2,3]])` = `1,3`

`np.array([[4,5,6]])` = `1,3`

`0` so we can think of it as `[[0]]` = `1,1`

So result `1,3+1+1+3` = `1,8`

which is the shape of result : `array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])`

Comment: Note that by second axis it means the horizontal axis

Answer (score 23):

I would explain this as follow.  It concats your first array into the **last dimension (axis)** of your last array in the function.

For example:

```
# both are 2 dimensional array
a = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = array([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
```

Now, let's take a look at `np.c_[a, b]` (use square brackets):

**First, let's look at the shape:**

The shape of both a and b are `(2, 3)`.  Concating a (2, 3) into the last axis of b (3), while keeping other axises unchanged (1) will become

```
(2, 3 + 3) = (2, 6)
```

That's the new shape.

**Now, let's look at the result:**

In b, the 2 items in the last axis are:

```
1st: [7, 8, 9]
2nd: [10, 11, 12]
```

Adding a to it means:

```
1st item: [1,2,3] + [7,8,9] = [1,2,3,7,8,9]
2nd item: [4,5,6] + [10,11,12] = [4,5,6,10,11,12]
```

So, the result is

```
[
  [1,2,3,7,8,9],
  [4,5,6,10,11,12]
]
```

It's shape is (2, 6)

Comment: This was the best explanation. Thanks for breaking it down this way.

Answer (score 14):

A short technique for concatenation of arrays using numpy is np.c_ and np.r_

np.c_[] concatenates arrays along second axis
but, np.r_[] concatenates arrays along first axis

Suppose:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
             [11,22,33]]
             )
b = np.array([[4,5,6],
             [44,55,66]]
             )
```

a's shape: (2,3) i.e. (no. of rows, no. of columns) also = (1st axis, 2nd axis)

b's shape: (2,3) i.e.(1st axis, 2nd axis)

np.r_ concatenates along the first axis
so np.r_[a,b] gives:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 22, 33],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [44, 55, 66]])
```

i.e. concatination along the rows(first axis), so number of rows will increase here.

While np.c_[a,b] concatenates along the Second axis i.e. columns here as below:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66]])
```

Comment: thanks! I found your answer easiest to understand!

Answer (score 9):

It converts several 1D arrays into a 2D array, with the single dimension of the original arrays preserved as the 1st dimension of the 2D array. The multiple input arrays are used as the 2nd dimension.

Think of it this way: If you have data series of 30 records apiece collected into separate 1D arrays, `np.c_` combines these series as you would in an excel table: side-by-side in separate columns of 30, rather than extending the first series.

For example, 2 starting arrays:

```
>>> arrayX = np.array([X1,X2...,X30])
array([X1, X2..., X30])
>>> arrayY = np.array([Y1,Y2...,Y30])
array([Y1, Y2..., Y30])
```

Let's see how `np.c_` combines them:

```
>>>arrayC = np.c_(arrayX, arrayY)
array([[X1, Y1],
       [X2, Y2],
       ...
       [X30, Y30]])
```

See how it's still 30 records long? You can now use the 2nd dimension to navigate between data series.

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) somewhat cryptically states: "Translates slice objects to concatenation along the second axis." *Second axis of what?* The resulting 2D array, they mean. It's unclear if you don't know that this a variation of `np.r_`, which concatenates along the first axis; and also if you don't think of a 1D array as *having* another dimension. But syntactically, it kinda does.

Query the shape of the arrays to illustrate this:

```
>>> np.shape(arrayX)
(30,)
>>> np.shape(arrayY)
(30,)
>>> np.shape(arrayC)
(30,2)
```

You can see a 2nd dimension, or axis, is created by the `np.c_` method, and the concatenation takes place there. By contrast:

```
>>> arrayR = np.r_[array1,array2]
array([X1, X2..., X30, Y1, Y2..., Y30])
>>> np.shape(arrayR)
(60,)
```

The `np.r_` method concatenates within the first dimension, or along the first axis.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is not a function, it is an object of class CClass.

```
it is "not a function, so takes no parameters
```

Above is what the official document said. you can check this question for details.

[numpy.r_ is not a function. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601001/numpy-r-is-not-a-function-what-is-it)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

I have 2 arrays with values:
`a = [x1,x2,x3]` 
`b = [y1,y2,y3]`

and we want to merge them together that we have something like: `[[x1, y1],[x2, y2],[x3, y3]]`.

Therefore we use `numpy.c_[a, b]`

```py
import numpy

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]  
value = numpy.c_[a,b]

print(value)
# [
#  [1, 4],
#  [2, 5],
#  [3, 6]
# ]
```

Answer (score -1):

np.c_[[1,4,5,4,5,3],[1,4,2,4,5,3],[2,4,6,8,9,0]]..This Concats The Arrays Horizontal or Say By Axis 0.So The Array Will be

```
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 2, 6],
       [4, 4, 8],
       [5, 5, 9],
       [3, 3, 0]])
```

***To Determine The Rows,***
Total Elements/Total no Of Arrays

(i.e 18/3)
[{len([1,4,5,4,5,3])}+{len([1,4,5,4,5,3])}+{len([2,4,6,8,9,0])}]//len([[1,4,5,4,5,3],[1,4,2,4,5,3],[2,4,6,8,9,0]])

So The Aboove One Gives 6..SO 6 rows will be there.

***For No of Colums,***
Total Elements/len(any one array inside the array)

for eg 18/len([1,4,5,4,5,3])

So The Columns will be 18/6 and That is 3.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 8 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here, including several others) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, please consider refraining from answering. Regarding your answer: Parts of your code aren't valid. And instead of the calculations you simply could use `a.shape` (with `a` the resulting array from `np.c_...`)?