# transforming a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of this form

```
[[-0.77947021  0.83822138]
[ 0.15563491  0.89537743]
[-0.0599077  -0.71777995]
[ 0.20759636  0.75893338]]
```

I want to create numpy array of this form `[x1, x2, x1*x2]` where `[x1, x2]` are from the original array list.

At the moment I am creating a list of list using python code, then converting it to numpy array. But I think there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
In [22]: import numpy as np

In [23]: x = np.array([[-0.77947021,  0.83822138],
    ...: [ 0.15563491,  0.89537743],
    ...: [-0.0599077,  -0.71777995],
    ...: [ 0.20759636,  0.75893338]])

In [24]: np.c_[x, x[:,0] * x[:,1]]
Out[24]: 
array([[-0.77947021,  0.83822138, -0.6533686 ],
       [ 0.15563491,  0.89537743,  0.13935199],
       [-0.0599077 , -0.71777995,  0.04300055],
       [ 0.20759636,  0.75893338,  0.15755181]])
```

This uses [`numpy.c_`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10894323/2647279), which is a convenience function to concatenate various arrays along their second dimension.

You can find some more info about concatenating arrays in Numpy's tutorial. Functions like `hstack` (see Jaime's answer), `vstack`, `concatenate`, `row_stack` and `column_stack` are probably the 'official' functions you should use. The functions `r_` and `c_` are a bit of hack to simulate some of Matlab's functionality. They are a bit ugly, but allow you write a bit more compactly.

Comment: Thanks "Bas Swinckles". Are there any quick tutorials for this?

Comment: I added a link to Numpy's tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There's a million different ways, I'd probably go with this:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(5, 2)
>>> np.hstack((x, np.prod(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)))
array([[ 0.39614232,  0.14416164,  0.05710853],
       [ 0.75068436,  0.61687739,  0.46308021],
       [ 0.90181541,  0.20365294,  0.18365736],
       [ 0.08172452,  0.36334486,  0.02969418],
       [ 0.61455203,  0.80694432,  0.49590927]])
```

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I am a newbie to numpy, was going the python comprehension path. I think this is cleaner.