# understand how this lambda function works

Tags: python, lambda

I thought I understood how lambda functions work, though I don't use them myself. But the lambda below from [this tutorial](https://github.com/dennybritz/nn-from-scratch/blob/master/nn-from-scratch.ipynb) totally stumps me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.linear_model
import matplotlib
```

That was easy. More:

```
# Generate a dataset and plot it
np.random.seed(0)
X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_moons(200, noise=0.20)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=40, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
clf = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV()
clf.fit(X, y)

# Helper function to plot a decision boundary.
# If you don't fully understand this function don't worry, it just generates the contour plot below.

def plot_decision_boundary(pred_func):

    # Set min and max values and give it some padding
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
    h = 0.01

    # Generate a grid of points with distance h between them
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

    # Predict the function value for the whole gid
    Z = pred_func(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

    # Plot the contour and training examples
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
```

Now the line I don't understand:

```
plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: clf.predict(x))
```

I've read many times how lambdas work, but I just don't get how the `x` here passing the correct values from before. How is the `x` mapped to the relevant values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is the concatenated Numpy object you pass in here:

```
Z = pred_func(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

`pred_func` is the argument to `plot_decision_boundary()`; by calling it you call the function object defined by the lambda. The above line translates to:

```
clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

Comment: That was great, thanks. Now I'll do some homework to get a deeper insight!

Answer (score 11):

lambdas are just anonymous functions. lambda bodies can only be an expression (as subset of what you can put into a function) because they have to fit inline with other code.

`plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: clf.predict(x))` could be rewritten as

```
def call_clf_predict(x):
    return clf.predict(x)
plot_decision_boundary(call_clf_predict)
```

Here, its more clear what is going on. `plot_decision_boundary` gets a callable and calls it with the single parameter `np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]`.

But lambda shouldn't have been used here in the first place. You could just do

```
plot_decision_boundary(clf.predict)
```

In the grand tradition of python tutorials, lambda is abused once again.

Comment: You are right, it works without using it. Very, very interesting.

Comment: I don't understand where does variable x gets its value

Comment: @VMMF - are you referring to the `x` parameter in the lambda function or the `X` in `plot_decision_boundary`? The lambda wasn't necessary. its `x` parameter is just forwarding the paramter it was called with to the function it calls. The big `X` is a global variable, visible in the function.

Comment: In the function you wrote, why isn't x passed : plot_decision_boundary(call_clf_predict). Is it because x is passed later inside plot_decision_boundary?

Answer (score 4):

```
plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: clf.predict(x))
```

This line is passing a function that takes a single argument into the method. When the lambda is evaluated, or the method is "called" with an argument `x`, it'll do `clf.predict(x)`

Within the method, that function is named `pred_func` and it is called with its single argument at

```
Z = pred_func(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

So the code that is ran is

```
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

Answer (score 2):

plot_decision_boundary(pred_func) actually requires three input `X,y,pred_func`

If `clf.predict(x)` only takes in `x` as its input, then no need for lambda.
However, for other prediction functions, which may require more inputs ( such as `func(parameters, x)` as the `pred_func`), and an outer function (`plot_decision_boundary`) that doesn't take in parameters, we need to insert them from the beginning:

```
plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: func(parameters, x), X, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

We want to plot the contours, so we need different coordinates for X axis, Y axis and the corresponding values of Z axis.

```
pred_func() is clf.predict(x), ie. the lambda function
```

So when you generate the meshgrid and concatenate it ([heres a good link to understand concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894323/what-does-the-c-underscore-expression-c-do-exactly)) and pass it into `pred_func` what you're doing is actually passing the values in the x argument of the lambda function which outputs the predictions from the lambda function `clf.predict()`ie. Z Matrix (outputs z, corresponding to different values of feature1 and feature2) which is used to plot the contours.